# [hdfs]how to configure different dfs.datanode.data.dir for each datanode?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, configure

I use ambari to setup a hadoop cluster.

but when I configure the hdfs's config. I found that if I modify the dfs.datanode.data.dir, the configure will take effect on all datanodes...

How could I configure different configs for each datanode?

for example, there are two disks in machine A, which is mounted to /data1, /data2

but there is only one disk in machine B, which is mounted to /data1

so I want to configure the dfs.datanode.data.dir to "/data1,/data2" for machine A.
but only "/data1" for machine B

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HDFS directories that don't exist will be ignored.  Put them all in, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that each Hadoop node in the cluster has its own set of configuration files too (under the usual conf\ dir). So you can login to that data-node machine and change config files.

The local configuration on data-node will take effect for that data-node.

Comment: Won't Ambari overwrite any hand-edited configuration?